# Javafx CSS: paint text with css

Tags: javafx-css

Is there a way to code in css like this image? transparent fill, blue stroke border, text in center. Sorry for my english.

[image: Spanish drag and drop image with blue stroke]

Answer (score 0):

Try using `fx-border-color` and `fx-stroke-dash-array` to create the dashed border.

For example,

```
-fx-border-color: deepskyblue;
-fx-fill: transparent;
-fx-stroke-dash-array: 10 10;
-fx-text-alignment: center;
```